Vite, Laravel and Vue.js - Error: Your current platform "undefined" and architecture "undefined"
Versions:
Node v20.14.0
npm 10.7.0
Laravel v10.17.0
I use Vite, Vue.js and Laravel. When I run "npm run dev" and I open up the browser, I get the following Javascript error in browser's console:
Uncaught Error: Your current platform "undefined" and architecture "undefined" combination is not yet supported by the native Rollup build. Please use the WASM build "@rollup/wasm-node" instead.

I have tried adding
"overrides": {
    "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node"
}

to package.json and also
overrides: {
    "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node"
}

to vite.config.js. I still get the same error, nothing changed. After changing package.json I ran npm run i and re-run npm run dev.
When creating new Vite project with Vue,js (npm create vite@latest) without laravel vite plugin, everything works. But I need it to work with laravel-vite-plugin.
Why doesn't Rollup recognize my platform and architecture? Why can't I override Rollup to use platform-independent version?

I have found the solution.
In my app.js file instead of having
import { createApp } from 'vue';

I used
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';

This post helped me: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/vue-feather/issues/8#issuecomment-787398213
